# Coordinates from 'dumpsys location' are censored on Huawei devices

Tags: huawei, location-services, dumpsys

I'd like to read coordinates from my Huawei P30 Pro via ADB by calling `adb shell dumpsys location`. However, the output is like:

```
Last Known Locations:
   gps: Location[gps 11******,14****** ...
```

They are censored with stars even though the GPS is already turned on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *this is a modification that Huawei did by themselves* (factual reasons not yet found). In short, **the method to print the location's detail was overwritten.**

`dumpsys` command calls the system services' dump method (more detail on [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487269/2821954)), and for `dumpsys location`, the respective service is `LocationManagerService`.

The [`dump()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java;l=3672;bpv=0;bpt=1) method for `LocationManagerService` (in Android 10, but also no major differences on previous versions) contains code like this:

```
...

pw.println("  Last Known Locations:");
for (Map.Entry<String, Location> entry : mLastLocation.entrySet()) {
    String provider = entry.getKey();
    Location location = entry.getValue();
    pw.println("    " + provider + ": " + location);
}

...
```

where it will iterate the last known locations from all location providers and print the name of the provider and its location. Note that the location is an instance of `Location` objects.

By default, the method to print the detail of the `Location` object ([`toString()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/location/java/android/location/Location.java;l=1100;bpv=0;bpt=1)) contains code like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("Location[");
    s.append(mProvider);
    s.append(String.format(" %.6f,%.6f", mLatitude, mLongitude));
    ...
```

where it will print the latitude and longitude in 6 decimal digits.

For many devices, this is the standard behavior, as shown on Nexus 5 with LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1):

```
 Last Known Locations:
    ...
    fused: Location[fused 1.234567,101.010101 acc=500 et=+12h00m00s000ms]
    ...
```

<sup>The numbers are changed due to privacy reason</sup>

By overriding the method, OEMs can customize how `dumpsys` will display the content. (Note: while [Android requires some services not to be modified](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#6_1_developer_tools), location is not one of them)

Comment: Thanks for your useful explanation. So, is there a device independent adb command i may use? In my case (python), i can only work with adb commands...

Comment: @mahack I haven't researched further nor tested it, but perhaps you could install 3rd-party apps that can get the GPS coordinates and output them to logcat, then use `adb logcat` instead.

Comment: thank you for your idea, I will keep this for a plan B. The problem is that I do not have the possibility to install an app for not having that permission.  But I got the problem with that toString() thing, could become a long way.