# get cellInfo with adb

Tags: adb, cellular-radio

I want to get the information inside cellinfo using adb command, but tac, lac, ci and cid are hidden. How to get these?

for example:

> mCi=9*****68 mTac=3****1

command:

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep -i mCellInfo
```

output:

```
mCellInfo=[CellInfoWcdma:{mRegistered=YES mTimeStamp=34662470924740ns mCellConnectionStatus=0 CellIdentityWcdma:{ mLac=3***1 mCid=2*****20 mPsc=233 mUarfcn=3028 mMcc=432 mMnc=11 mAlphaLong=IR-MCI mAlphaShort=IR-MCI mAdditionalPlmns={} mCsgInfo=null} CellSignalStrengthWcdma: ss=2147483647 ber=0 rscp=-24 ecno=0 level=0}]
```

device: samsung galaxy a32

android version: 12

Comment: I'm afraid this is a modification done by Samsung (similar to [`dumpsys location` on Huawei](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224041/44325)), because the values are shown in plain text on Pixel 3a, Android 12.